# Touch Authentication Feature MobileFirst 7.0 not working

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to implement the Touch Authentication feature in a sample app of MobileFirst 7.0. I am following the steps mentioned in the URL

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklightsmobileplayground/entry/touchid_authentication_with_worklight?lang=en

I am facing two issues:-

1) I have to insert a code snippet in cordova_plugins.js. When I do that, my app hangs on the splash screen.

2) Prior to that, when I import the two native files in the Classes folder, the Xcode fails to make the build.

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you able to run the sample from the link? Also, what code snippet are you inserting into cordova_plugins.js?

Comment: The sample is also not working and the code snippet is as follows:-

{
                  "file": "../js/TouchID.js",
                  "id": "nl.x-services.plugins.touchid.TouchID",
                  "clobbers": [
                               "window.plugins.touchid"
                               ]
}

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you attempt integrating the plug-in by following the similar instructions that are provided in the following blog post, which details how to do so for 3rd party Cordova plug-ins in MobileFirst Hybrid applications: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2015/08/03/integrating-3rd-party-cordova-plug-ins/.

I am guessing that you may have not properly edited the plug-in's JS file, which requires some wrapping, as detailed in the above blog post.

Comment: OK. Thanks for the help :)